# Hashing data regardless of order

Tags: c#, hash

This is kind of a really basic question to ask, but is there any type of hashing functionality that the output will be the same regarding of data position?

For example, the MD5 hash of abc is 900150983cd24fb0d6963f7d28e17f72, but the MD5 hash of cba is 3944b025c9ca7eec3154b44666ae04a0.

Is there any implementation that will get these to come out the same.

Perhaps hashing is the right method to achieve this and if so can anybody recommend a different solution?

Thanks

Comment: This will soon be closed as Too Broad, but meantime: Sort the characters in the string, *then* hash. Now you're always hashing "abc" regardless of the order in which they first showed up.

Comment: Sure. For example, ensure consistent ordering of the string (e.g. `abc -> abc, cba -> abc`). Or use a hash that doesn't depend on ordering (e.g. CRC, XOR). Of course, the performance may suffer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For cryptographic hashes, no. The very purpose of a cryptographic hash like MD5 is that even very similar inputs yield totally different outputs. This is to prevent giving hints to people trying to crack the hash.

As suggested in the comments, you'd have to sort your string contents to be exactly the same. This increases the risk of collisions; if security is your purpose, then just don't do this.